# Regex To Exclude First Part of String

Tags: regex, google-analytics

New at this so thanks in advance for the help.

I'm looking to write a Regex that will match the end of the string but not the beginning and there are some cases where the string is only one character.

Here are the sample strings and I'm trying to match only the items shown, otherwise there is no match.

```
/en-ca/brand/atf-type-f/  # should match /brand/atf-type-f/ 
/                         # no match
/en-ca                    # no match
/en-ca/                   # no match
/es-xl                    # no match
/en-gb                    # no match
/ru-kz/                   # no match
/knowledge-centre/sds     # should match /knowledge-centre/sds
/en-us/brand/purity-fg    # should match /brand/purity-fg
```

The Regex engine I'm using to Google Analytics and I'm looking to output the Page Path without the country ID and the language ID.

Comment: Please include what the actual outputs are from the sample inputs you gave us.  Also include anything you may have already tried.

Comment: Also include the language or regex engine you're using. If I understand correctly, for `/` and `/en-ca`, etc. you don't want any matches? What exactly are the rules that tell us to match `knowledge-centre` but not `en-us`?

Comment: @ctwheels thanks. Yes, I don't want to match the / or the /en-ca Just everything behind there. Basically I have a Requester URI and I want to remove the country and language from the URI and return everything else.

Comment: Google Analytics is quite limited with regex capabilities at the moment. You can't use a negation in your regex, so you're limited to this: 1. Create a regex filter for *Only Show*: `^/([^/]+)(/[^/]+)*/?$`. 2. Create a regex filter for *Don't Show* to exclude some records: `^/\w{2}-\w{2}/?$`. I don't think you can remove `/en-us/` and similar from start of strings though; not certain.

Comment: @ctwheels I think you're right. I was thinking I could use a look back and go all the way back to the /en-us/ and stop there but I couldn't figure-out how to do that.

Comment: @Kirk lookbehinds, lookaheads, and other constructs aren't available in GA, so you're extremely limited in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.

Using the Advanced Filter within GA I:

1) Used regex with ^(/..-..)?(/)?(.*)

2) used the Output To -> Constructor to put up the groups I wanted. Each () within GA Output Constructor is numbered. Therefore $A1 pickups first part and so on. Therefore just returning $A3 gave me the path. Had to added / back in at the beginning so the output statement became /$A3

Hope this help someone else.